# How to autofill rows in one column with conditioning of other column data?

Tags: pandas, autofill

I have a dataframe A:

```
   State     Region   Code
0  Texas     Texas      1
1            Houston    0
2            Dallas     0
3            Austin     0
4  Michigan  Michigan   1
5            Ann Arbor  0
6            Yipsilanti 0
7  Alaska    Alaska     1
8            Troy       0
```

I would like to fill out all the states with state above if code =0, expect to get output like:

```
   State     Region   Code   Group
0  Texas     Texas      1      1
1  Texas     Houston    0      1
2  Texas     Dallas     0      1
3  Texas     Austin     0      1
4  Michigan  Michigan   1      2
5  Michigan  Ann Arbor  0      2
6  Michigan  Yipsilanti 0      2
7  Alaska    Alaska     1      3
8  Alaska    Troy       0      3
```

I have tried to add a new column "Group" to separate above data into 3 groups and then use groupby to fillout the State

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
t1 = pd.Series({'State':'Texas', 'RegionalName':'Texas', 'Code':1})
t2 = pd.Series({'State':'  ', 'RegionalName':'Houston','Code' :0})
df=pd.DataFrame([t1,t2])
df.columns=['State','Region','Code']
```

read from txt.file to generate above dataframe:

```
df['Group'] = np.where(df['Code'] == 1, df['Code'+1, df['Code'])
```

then it doesn't work. Any suggestion? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `cumsum` for `Group` and `ffill` for `State`:

```
df['Group'] = df['Code'].eq(1).cumsum()
df['State'] = df['State'].ffill()
```

Output:

```
      State      Region Code  Group
0     Texas       Texas    1      1
1     Texas     Houston    0      1
2     Texas      Dallas    0      1
3     Texas      Austin    0      1
4  Michigan    Michigan    1      2
5       Ann       Arbor    0      2
6       Ann  Yipsilanti    0      2
7    Alaska      Alaska    1      3
8    Alaska        Troy    0      3
```

Comment: Thank you. it works in a new set. If my first column was generated from program, which has space ' ' for none value, it seems doesn't work. I tried NaN to replace ' ', use df.fillna(method='ffill'), it didn't work either.  Any smart way to remove space " to allow it work? Thank you

Comment: `df['State'] = df['State'].mask(df['State'].eq(' ')).ffill()`? Or `df['State'] = df['State'].mask(df['Code'].eq(0)).ffill()`?

Comment: Super Cool, Thank you!

Comment: @Pinkmei you're welcome. If it answers your question, please consider upvote/accept the answer.

Comment: df['State'] = df['State'].mask(df['State'].eq(' ')).ffill() works well in my case. Yes, I have accepted the answer. As I am new to stackoverflow, I can't upvote it yet until my reputation goes over 15. Thank you.